# Is this Tensorflow bias vector shaped correctly?

Tags: regression, classification, tensorflow

In the text I read the following:

[image: code]

I’m confused on the dimensions of the bias vector. How can we add a`(m,1)` vector to a`(1, p)` vector?  Is `w0` shaped correctly? Or should `w1` be shaped `(n, P)` to account for `P` classes, and the we broadcast `w0`?

Note: I assume `w1` should be `(n, P)` so that our matrix multiplication yields a row of unnormalized logits for each class prediction for each observation. Then does it make sense to add a per-class bias and broadcast that to the number of samples in our data?

I feel foolish for even asking but walking through the example I couldn’t reconcile...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's walk through the matrix arithmetic.
The matrix-vector product $Xw_1$ has shape $(m,n)(n,1)$, so the result has shape $(m,1)$. We can think of this as each *row* of `X` being mapped to a scalar. This doesn't match with the text's description: the intent appears to be to have an output for each class, i.e. multinomial logistic regression. For this to be multinomial logistic regression, we would need to have `w_1` with shape $(n,P)$.

I don't recall TF's broadcasting rules but if this code executes without raising shape-related exceptions, it's probably because of behind-the-scenes broadcasting. This should be easy enough to validate: supply some data and check if there is a constant difference between each value of `Y_hat`.

Mistakes like these are why I advocate for writing unit tests for neural network models, as I do here: [What should I do when my neural network doesn't learn?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/352036/what-should-i-do-when-my-neural-network-doesnt-learn/352037#352037)